# next-css with option cssModules:true exclude node_module css files

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, next.js

I have one `next.js` project setup with following `next.config.js` as below

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true
})
```

It works fine when you use as below

Create a CSS file style.css

```
.example {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Create a page file pages/index.js

```
import css from "../style.css"

export default () => <div className={css.example}>Hello World!</div>
```

But when I use without css module  it doesn't work when I use css class instead of css module.

At least I want to exclude `node_modules` css files.